# my question is about recursion of continued fraction

Tags: continued-fractions

1 is not equals 2, then whats wrong with the following...
1=2/(3-1) and if we replace (can we or cannot?) 1 on right hand side by 1=2/(3-1) that is
1=2/(3-2/(3-1)) and if we continue replacing 1 on right hand side that is
1=2/(3-2/(3-2/(3-2/(3-2/(3-2/(3-... ---(A)

similarly 
2=2/(3-2)
2=2/(3-2/(3-2/(3-2/(3-2/(3-2/(3-... ---(B)

this says (A)=(B) or 1 = 2
kindly explain what is not mathematical here

Comment: I cover a lot of this in [a similar question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3555625/negative-solution-for-continued-fraction-1-1-11/3555647#3555647). The short version is that the "finite" versions of the fraction -- what we would call a convergent -- converge only to one of the values. This is what we would say the infinite fraction "equals." What that "$\cdots$" represents matters a lot, especially in how the infinite process you do converges to a given value.

Comment: I would find it a lot easier to read your question if you had used MathJax.

Comment: so the correct answer is, a rational number has a finite continued fraction?

Comment: Yes a rational number has a finite continued fraction.  I don't know how that corresponds to your question.

Comment: thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$${2\over3-{2\over3-2_{\ddots}}}$$ has to be interpreted as the limit of $$2,{2\over3-2},{2\over3-{2\over3-2}},\dots$$ and not as the limit of $$1,{2\over3-1},{2\over3-{2\over3-1}},\dots$$